# Как создать сортировку двумерного массива по возрастанию с#

Tags: c#, массивы, пузырьковая-сортировка

Как создать сортировку двумерного массива, по возрастанию? Второй день ломаю голову и ни к чему не прихожу, нужна помощь :( на c#

Например есть массив

- 4,7,8
- 5,2,3
- 6,7,9

Как сделать сортировку его так, что бы получился по возрастанию, то бишь

- 2,3,4
- 5,6,7
- 7,8,9

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Для двумерного массива сразу возникает вопрос - по возрастанию чего? И по столбцам или по строкам сортировка? Для двумерного массива нужно уточнять эти детали. И приводить наглядные примеры - было так, а после сортировки должно получиться вот так.

Comment: Чтоб элементы начиная от 0;0 шли по возрастанию,  до последнего. Например как в массиве{ 4,2,6}{5,9,1}.. Чтоб получилось {1,2,4}{5,6,9}

Answer (score 3):

1. Надо сложить все элементы двумерного массива в одномерный (двойной цикл)
2. Отсортировать одномерный массив
3. Из одномерного массива положить данные в многомерный, пробегаясь от начала одномерного к его концу (можно также использовать два цикла)

---

Второй вариант:

Если представить, что двумерный массив, это одномерный (ведь у него также индексы идут с 0 до N по возрастанию.....можно представить, что это змея, которая свернулась несколько раз), то можно спокойно применять метод сортировки одномерного массива с поправкой на то, что будут два цикла. ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: Ну либо `unsafe` и как память.

Comment: Для сортировки двумерного массива подойдёт однострочник `array.Cast<int>().OrderBy(v => v)`, а вот как получить дальше снова двумерный массив без циклов, не соображу что-то.

Answer (score 1):

Пример по методу [Алексея Шиманского](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/191482/%D0%90%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%B9-%D0%A8%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9):

```
Console.Clear();

int[,] myMatrix = new int[3, 3]
{
            {4,7,8},
            {5,2,3},
            {6,7,9}
};

Console.WriteLine($"####### DEFAULT MATRIX #######\n");
PrintArray(myMatrix);

int[] myArray = new int[9];
int z = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < myMatrix.GetLength(0); i++)
    for (int j = 0; j < myMatrix.GetLength(1); j++)
    {
        myArray[z] = myMatrix[i, j];
        z++;
    }

for (int i = 0; i < myArray.Length; i++) { }
int[] result = myArray.OrderBy(i => i).ToArray();
for (int i = 0; i < result.Length; i++) { }

Console.WriteLine($"####### SORT MATRIX #######\n");

int[,] sortMyMatrix = new int[3, 3];
int k = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < sortMyMatrix.GetLength(0); i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < sortMyMatrix.GetLength(1); j++)
    {
        sortMyMatrix[i, j] = result[k];
        Console.Write($"{sortMyMatrix[i, j]}\t");
        k++;
    }
    Console.WriteLine($"\n");
}

void PrintArray(int[,] matr)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < matr.GetLength(0); i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < matr.GetLength(1); j++)
            Console.Write($"{matr[i, j]}\t");
        Console.WriteLine($"\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: Постарайтесь делать ваши ответы более развёрнутыми и добавлять в них больше объяснения. Подробнее [в справке](//ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Ответ можно отредактировать кнопкой «[править](//ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/1490871/edit)».